# Signing an OKX API v5 request using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cryptocurrency

I wrote the following code that gets my account balance on OKX, And no output is coming out :

```
# Vars :
  api_url='https://www.okx.com/'
  api_key='some_api_key'
  sec_key='some_sec_key'
  passphrase='some_passphrase'
  api_name='some_api_name' 
  time_stamp=$(date -u +%FT%T.%3NZ)     
  body="{}"
  pre_hash="${time_stamp}GET/api/v5/account/balance${sec_key}"
  sign=$(echo -n $pre_hash | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac $sec_key | base64)
  exp_time=$(date "+%s%N" | cut -b-13)
  
  # Request :
  curl \
    --silent \
    -X 'GET' \
    -H 'accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H "OK-ACCESS-KEY: $api_key" \
    -H "OK-ACCESS-SIGN: $sign" \
    -H "OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP: $time_stamp" \
    -H "OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE: $passphrase" \
    -H "expTime: $exp_time" \
    'https://www.okx.com/api/v5/account/balance' | jq
```

Official docs [https://www.okx.com/docs-v5/en/#overview-rest-authentication] says :

- Create a prehash string of timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where + represents String concatenation).
- Prepare the SecretKey.
- Sign the prehash string with the SecretKey using the HMAC SHA256.
- Encode the signature in the Base64 format.

I am not sure, But I think the issue is in my [pre_hash, sign] variables I wrote .
Unfortunatily, Many answers are about OKX old API version, And most of them are for python .